# React-Native, IOS, Firebase - Canot distrubte to AppStore due to "loop"

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, app-store, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to push our app to appstore and during distribution it failed due to the issue :

> ERROR ITMS-90158: "The following URL schemes found in your app are not in the correct format: [https://XXXXX.co, https://XXXXX.co/event]. URL schemes need to begin with an alphabetic character, and be comprised of alphanumeric characters, the period, the hyphen or the plus sign only. Please see RFC1738 for more detail."

It solves only when I change "CFBundleURLSchemes" from Array to String

Before:

```
  <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>Editor</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
                <string>app</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                    <array>
                <string>https://XXXXX.co/event</string>
                    </array>
            </dict>
```

After:

```
  <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>Editor</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
                <string>app</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <string>https://XXXXX.co/event</string> 
    </dict>
```

But when  I try to run, the app crashes during:

> [FIRApp configure];

The error:

> -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]: array argument is not an NSArray
>   2019-08-28 20:34:47.876651+0300 App[642:125815] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]: array argument is not an NSArray'

on line in FIRApp.m:

> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kFIRAppReadyToConfigureSDKNotification
>                                                         object:self
>                                                       userInfo:appInfoDict];

Now I'm in a loop - cannot run without array and connot push to appstore

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Those are not URL schemes.  `https://XXXXX.co/event` is a URL.  The scheme is the part before the `://`.

So your scheme could be `XXXXX.co`.  In that case a deeplink might look like `XXXXX.co://event?foo=bar` which, when invoked on a mobile device, would open your app and pass along that URL.

To fix, you'd need to change the value of `CFBundleURLScheme` to `<string>XXXXX.co</string>` and change wherever else you have that scheme defined.

Comment: so remove the "https" ?

Comment: the error message describes what the scheme can be: `URL schemes need to begin with an alphabetic character, and be comprised of alphanumeric characters, the period, the hyphen or the plus sign only` so that excludes the `://` and any other slashes

Comment: Now I have the issue: ERROR: Specified custom URL scheme is https://XXXXX.co/event but Info.plist do not contain such scheme in CFBundleURLTypes key.

Comment: Two problems: 1)  XXXXX.co/event is not a valid scheme - please read above! - no slashes.   2) you probably have to change what ever was in the CFBundleURLTypes key to be the same value.